# Dovecot: ssl-params: Generating SSL parameters

Tags: ssl, dovecot

What is the message:

`dovecot: ssl-params: Generating SSL parameters`

inside logs telling me? I did not change anything on server settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Dovecot [documentation](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/SSL/DovecotConfiguration#line-108):

> When Dovecot starts up for the first time, it generates new 512bit and 1024bit Diffie Hellman parameters and saves them into /var/lib/dovecot/ssl-parameters.ssl. After the initial creation they're by default regenerated every week.

Most likely this is the case.

Comment: No, it wasn't. It's running for >1 week now incl SSL.

Comment: Ok. Can you give more data? Did it happened just after Dovecot started? Does it happen periodically or just once? And enable `verbose_ssl = yes` to obtain more data.

Comment: It just happen without chaning configuration and restarting or anything.

Comment: @frlan That's exactly what Nikolay wrote: »they're by default regenerated every week.«

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh..... I missed that point. Thanks.